# android.view.WindowLeaked: at release.apk only not debug.apk

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I made an app that use zxing.
It get isbn code from integrated-zxing and send POST to server.

... and it works perfectly when it builded debug mode but doesn't works when it builded release.

I don't know what is wrong.

I already see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215988/progress-dialog-and-asynctask-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651428/fatal-exception-asynctask-1-doinbackground), I've tried, it didn't help for me.

please help. It tied me to a chair.

Here the exception:

```
11-29 11:36:22.233  14848-14899/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at a.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.df.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at a.a.b.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.df.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
        at a.a.b.k.d(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.k.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.df.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-29 11:36:22.258    2003-2022/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
11-29 11:36:23.778    1844-1844/? E/DataRouter﹕ usb connection is true
11-29 11:36:23.778    1844-1844/? E/DataRouter﹕ InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is success
11-29 11:36:25.778    1844-1844/? E/DataRouter﹕ usb connection is true
11-29 11:36:25.783    1844-1844/? E/DataRouter﹕ InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is success
11-29 11:36:27.783    1844-1844/? E/DataRouter﹕ usb connection is true
11-29 11:36:27.783    1844-1844/? E/DataRouter﹕ InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is success
11-29 11:36:29.213  14848-14848/? E/WindowManager﹕ Activity lemon.apple.aladinisbna.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@415ac750 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity lemon.apple.aladinisbna.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@415ac750 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:386)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.b.a.onPreExecute(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at lemon.apple.aladinisbna.MainActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3035)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1189)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is code :

```
//ISBNDownLoader.java
public class ISBNDownLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Book> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayAdapter<Book> adapter;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ISBNDownLoader(Context context, ArrayAdapter<Book> adapter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {// works fine until here...
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "잠시만 기다려 주세요 ...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Book doInBackground(String... params) {
        String isbn = params[0];
        return requestPostToAladin(isbn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Book result) { // guess here is where the crash occur, I think
        if (result == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "알라딘에서 해당 도서를 찾을 수 없네요 ㅠㅠ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Book.save(context, result);
            adapter.insert(result, 0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public Book requestPostToAladin(String isbn) {
        // send POST to sever
        // using jsoup
        ...
    }
}

//ScanISBNFragment.java
public class ScanISBNFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_scan) {
            IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(getActivity()); // call zxing.
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void search(String isbn) {
        ISBNDownLoader isbnDownLoader = new ISBNDownLoader(getActivity(), (ArrayAdapter<Book>) listView.getAdapter());
        isbnDownLoader.execute(isbn);
    }

    ...

}

// MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity { // LAUNCH Activity, and implement navigation drawer.

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // I have to implement this Main"Activity" because  IntentIntegrator.initiateScan() supports Activity only.
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanResult != null) {
            String contents = scanResult.getContents();
            if (contents != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, contents, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ScanISBNFragment placeholder = (ScanISBNFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
                assert placeholder != null;
                if (placeholder.isISBN(contents)) {
                    placeholder.search(contents); // here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ISBN이 아니네요! 다시 찍어주세요.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    ...

}
```

I'm using Android Studio 0.3.6 on Mac

So, here is build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'android'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // secret!
            storeFile file("****")
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "****"
            keyPassword "****"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.1.4@aar'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
}
```

**SOLUTION:**
 the problem is occur from invalid proguard.
so.. I just remove proguard. then, everythings works fine.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. the problem was occured from proguard-rules.txt

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in **onPostExecute**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Book result) { // guess here is where the crash occur, I think
        if (dialog!= null || dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss(); 
        }
        if (result == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "알라딘에서 해당 도서를 찾을 수 없네요 ㅠㅠ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Book.save(context, result);
            adapter.insert(result, 0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried this but could not solve the problem. 
But thanks, You remind me to be part of the problem.